# Checking most played move in a position in Fritz

Tags: chessbase, fritz

I have a series of about 50 games in a certain position in fritz opening database 2013. I want to check the most played move, but rather than checking which move was most played by checking them individually, I want to know how to do it like in chess.com's openings database.

Comment: Does converting the games to an opening database work?

Comment: How can I do that in Deep Fritz 14?